# Как вывести не известный сhild [FireBase]?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

У меня есть Firebase, где есть "service" - Название сервиса, "HTC, sam" - название устройства. Как взять все данные из всех устройств (сколько бы их не было) и из всех Service (сколько бы их не было)? [onDataChange внутри onDataChange?]  [image: введите сюда код]

Answer (score 0):

Идейно код должен работать за исключением этапов циклов. Но как то так сделать можно.

```
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/service/devices/");
root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){
            // Тут получаешь данные с по названиям телефонов
            DataSnapshot dS = ((DataSnapshot)i.next());


            for (DataSnapshot dS1 : dS.getChildren()) {
                // Тут получаешь данные с likes

                    for (DataSnapshot dS2 : dS1.getChildren()) {
                        // тут уже data value
                        String data = dS2.child("data").getValue().toString();
                        String value = dS2.child("мфдгу").getValue().toString();
                    }
                }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```